# How to modify a properties file in spring boot jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jar

I am writing a Spring Boot Application.
This application talks to  a Main Frame through MessageQueues

So inorder to talk to that MainFrame we are provided with a java jar(which has the code that talks to MessageQueues ). lets call it proxy jar.

We have to use the operations written from the above mentioned proxy jar .
We dont write any code to read/write to MessageQueues (IBM MessageQueues) in our application, this is done by the proxy jar and its dependent runtime jar.

So here comes the problem, this Proxy jar is coded in such a way that it looks for a file called 'commcfg.properties' in the classpath (expects the name to be exactly same). Actually the Proxy jar uses another dependent jar (lets call runtime jar)which reads the queue details from commcfg.properties and reads/writes from Message Queues.

commcfg.properties have the values of MessageQueue and Host and port of those Queues . In short Queue details.

So the trouble is these MessageQueue details will be different in different environments. I need to use the commcfg.properties according to environment

So far my trials to solve this.

1. Lets say I have two environments .
   So I will have two different set of values of commcfg.properties

   I have created files as follows
   commcfg.DEV.properties
   commcfg.PROD.properties so that they will be in classpath

   Next I have written code such that it will pick up the particular property 
   file depending on Environment and rename it to commcfg.properties(as the 
   Proxy jar and its helper dependent Runtime jar need the exact name to be 
   commcfg.properties).

   In my local workspace I could do this .
   But when deployed (we use docker) that gets packaged into spring boot jar.

   So my hack is not working as we cannot rename files with in jars.
2. Another thought I had:

   Before I call my functionality code , I will put  the commcfg.properties in 
   class path (project/src/main/resources) 
   I will read it and modify the values as needed per environment.
   The values I will have them in application.properties.
   But again I doubt that with in jar I cannot modify the file.

Hoping I am clear 
Kindly help me out..

Comment: If I udnerstood you correctly: you cannot use nothing else but a particular properties file (you cannot use Spring ways to configure your app using Environment/class properties)? In such case probably the only solution is to provide your commcfg.properties file in your classpath, but outside of your jar (e.g. somewhere in the root directory where jar is placed). Then, you add this root dir to your classpath, so you can easily modify it.

Comment: Just to add to what @MikeWojtyna said, some of the common approaches in such cases are 1. use Spring cloud config server with properties for differnt environments. 2. Put the properties files in jenkins, and let jenkins pick the correponding file during building

Comment: Thank you @mike 
and Kiran

Can you please advise If I can do tweak this during maven build phase?

Answer (score 2):

In spring boot, You can register your properties file with a Java annotation `@PropertySource`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:commcfg.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
    SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfig.class);
}
```

}

and let the commcfg.properties file contain the DEV environment details

```
messageQueue.name=myMessageQueue
messageQueue.host=host
messageQueue.port=4040
```

Now build your jar file and you get **yourjar.jar**

Now run it in DEV environment with default values

```
java -jar yourjar.jar
```

run it in QA environment with overriding the default values in your config file

```
java -jar --messageQueue.name=diffrenthost --messageQueue.host=diffrenthost --messsageQueue.port=diffrentport yourjar.jar
```

This way you can override your default values. I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but this won't solve my issue. I have tried this solution earlier.
The commcfg.properties file (containing the queue details) is not used by my spring boot app. These values are used by non-spring Java code(proxy jars) which my spring boot is dependent on.

Comment: is there anyway to do something similiar, but after the jar has been built?

Answer (score 0):

you can put the properties files on the same path of spring-boot jar, the config items can override the properties in the jar.